# Infinite for in C++

Tags: c++, loops, vector, std

I want to loop over a `std::vector` over and over again until I break from the loop. Is this the best way?

```
int main() {
std::string str;
std::ifstream infile;
std::vector<int> vec;
std::set<int> sums;
int sum = 0;
sums.insert(sum);
infile.open("Text.txt");
while (!infile.eof()) {
    getline(infile, str);
    vec.push_back(std::stoi(str));
}
infile.close();

while (true) {
    for (int i : vec) {
        sum += i;
        if (sums.count(sum)) {
            std::cout << sum;           
            return 0;
        }
        sums.insert(sum);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: the code isnt doing what you describe because you left out essential parts (there is no `break`) hence it hard to say what is "best"

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: The code you show does indeed for ever and ever repeat the inner part, which loops over the vector (assuming a few things you did not show). Now you need to define "best". Consider having a look at the tag https://stackoverflow.com/tags/optimization/info, it offers a nice choice of things to base your definition on. My favorite one is "teacher happiness".

Comment: you should do it Asynchronously as I believe this will run on UI thread

Comment: Are you doing anything to `vec` in the loop, and if so, what?

Comment: the `foreach` tag is explicitly about `foreach` "In contrast to a for loop". I removed the tag because what you have is a for loop

Comment: @NoobCode how comes? I believe this code is used to launch space shuttles. Who is right?

Comment: It's definitely not a good way, because there _is_  no break whatsoever in your code.

Comment: Aside: this will stop as soon as it sees a `0`, or some negative values.

Comment: @NoobCoder what UI? it's all in `main`, reading from `cin` and writing to `cout`

Comment: @Caleth I mean it will run on Main(UI) thread

Comment: @NoobCoder there is no UI for this to block

Comment: When do you think your code will break ? I don't see that. 
Besides, and almost: what is your goal doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the algorithms library and do something like:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
// initialize vec here
while (std::none_of(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int i) {
    // return true here to break
    return false;
}));
```

Comment: Clever.  Maybe good, maybe bad, but clever.